# «Сардины в масле» тунисского производства

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, смысл

Уместны ли здесь кавычки? Если убрать их — получится масло тунисского производства, а это неверно по смыслу.

**Копеечные «сардины в масле» тунисского производства и кусок хлеба, испеченного местной пекарней — вот нехитрые продукты, купленные на обед в супермаркете городских окраин.**

Comment: Выражение "супермаркет городских окраин" вызывает сомнение. Один супермаркет на все окраины?

Comment: "Кусок хлеба, испеченного местной пекарней, — вот..." Причастный оборот следует выделять с двух сторон.

Comment: Порт-Луи - город небольшой. Один супермаркет на весь городок и находится он не в центре, ближе к окраинам.

Comment: "Находится ближе к окраинам" преобразовалось в "супермаркет  окраин"? Я бы воздержался от таких ходов. "Супермаркет на окраине (города)" - простенько и со вкусом.

Comment: Так оно и было изначально, но заметив повторяющееся дважды  "на": "на обед" + "на окраине", я заменил второй вариант. Может быть я ошибаюсь, но, по-моему, таких повторений следует избегать.

Comment: А если написать "купленные к обеду"? Так даже вернее.

Comment: Да, так лучше. Вот таких предложений и фраз у меня - тысячи: в одном месте поправляешь, а в другом...

Comment: В Нацкорпусе все куплено "к обеду", единственное исключение — из коллекции анекдотов.

Answer (score 1):

Можно не придираться, выражение *сардины в масле тунисского производства* понятно всем. Если хотите большей точности, то я бы предложил описательное *сардины тунисского производства в масле*. А если говорите о названии продукта, то используйте прописную букву: *"Сардины в масле" тунисского производства.*

Answer (score 1):

**Копеечные «сардины в масле» тунисского производства и кусок хлеба, испеченного местной пекарней, – вот нехитрые продукты, купленные на обед в супермаркете городских окраин.**

Я думаю, что кавычки следует оставить. В этом случае сочетание будет являться упрощенным названием продукта (пишется  со строчной буквы).

Кавычки определяют, что  два определения относятся именно к словосочетанию, и это надо обозначить.

Comment: Виктор, обратите внимание на добавленную запятую.

Comment: Ок, поправил у себя в тексте.